# Tab key, arrow keys and page up/down keys donot work on Firefox on Ubuntu 1.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, firefox3.6

I am using **Ubuntu 10.04** and **Firfox 3.6.3**. The tab key, arrow keys and page up / down keys have suddenly stopped working when on Firefox. They work fine on any other application (like Google chrome). I am not sure what is happening and how they got disabled, only for firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by removing Delicious Firefox plugin. It was not compatible with the firefox version I was using.

Answer (score 1):

tools|Options|Advanced|General tab - uncheck the first option for cursor key

Comment: The problem was resolved by removing Delicious Firefox plugin.